# Mysql How to add a column as varchar(21884) with UTF8 charset?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I execute this query:

```
CREATE TABLE `varchar_test1` (
  `id`  tinyint(1)  NOT NULL,
   `cloumn_1` varchar(21844) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

it is ok.

If I then execute this:

```
ALTER TABLE `varchar_test1` ADD COLUMN `cloumn_2` varchar(21844) NOT NULL;
```

I get an error:

> ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

If I execute this:

```
CREATE TABLE `varchar_test2` (
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cloumn_1` varchar(21844) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I get:

> ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

Why?

Running `mysql --version` returns

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for macos10.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your columns store multi-byte values and thus exceed the maximum row size.

As explained in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html), MySQL tables have a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes, regardless of the engine you use. Adding your two `varchar(21844)` columns means you go over this limit. This happens because the `CHARSET` on your table is `utf8` (currently an alias for `utf8mb3`), so [each character of a `varchar` in your table takes a maximum of 3 bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) (plus 2 bytes to store the length). That's fine with one column of 21,844 characters, but not with two.

To fix this, use `TEXT` (or `TINYTEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, etc.) instead of `VARCHAR` columns. This will cause the values to be stored separately, so each of your columns will actually only contribute a few bytes to the row size. (This is also explained in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html).)

Also, FYI: the spelling is `column`, not `cloumn`.